# Number Theory problem

Tags: functional-analysis

A non-negative integer $f(n)$ is assigned to each positive integer $n$ in such a way that the following conditions are satisfied:

(a) $f(mn) = f(m) +f(n)$, for all positive integers $m$ and $n$.
(b) $f(n) = 0$, whenever the final (right-hand) decimal digit of $n$ is $3$.
(c) $f(10) = 0$.

Prove that $f(n) =0$ for all integer $n$.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. If you think that this is a number theory question, then why did you use that `functional-analysis` tag?

Comment: Please have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).

Comment: HINT: argue by contradiction. Let $N$ be the minimum number such that $f(N) \neq 0$. Can you show that it is a prime number? Moreover, recall that $$f(mn) = f(n) + f(m) \ge f(n)$$ can you show that every prime has a multiple such that its final digit is $3$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I'm perplexed. As I read the time stamps, it looks like the tag was "functional-equations" when you posted your comment, and that the OP changed it to "functional-analysis" in response. The original tag seems OK to me, since the problem, after all, is asking for all *functions* that satisfy a batch of given conditions.

Comment: @BarryCipra I read `functional-analysis`and I don't recall having seen the `functional-equations` tag being used for this question.

Comment: Every *odd* prime has a multiple that ends in 3. Multiples of 2 have to be handled separately - which is why we are told that $f(10)=0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I believe you. It could just be a quirk in the way different things get time stamped.

Comment: @gandalf61, you need to deal separately with the odd prime 5 as well as 2, since no multiple of 5 ends in 3. (But $f(10)=f(2)+f(5)$ handles both.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$By $(a)$, we would need $f(1) =f(1\cdot 1) = f(1) + f(1) = 2f(1) \implies f(1) = 0$.

If $n = \prod_{i=1}^k\,p_i^{e_i}$, where the $p_i$ are prime and $e_i\geqslant 0$, we have by repeated use of $(a)$ that

$$f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^k\, e_if(p_i),\tag{$*$}$$

so $f$ is entirely defined by its value on the primes.

$\quad(\mathrm I)$: If $p$ is a prime that ends in $3$ or $7$, $p^k$ ends in $3$ for $k=1$ or $3$.
Therefore, from  $(a)$ and $(b)$ we conclude $0 = f(p^k) = kf(p) \implies f(p) = 0$.

$\quad(\mathrm{II})$: If $p$ is a prime that ends in $1$ or $9$, $p^k$ ends in $1$ for $k=1$ or $2$.
Then $3p^k$ ends in $3$ and hence by $(a)$ and $(b)$ we conclude $0 = f(3p^k) = \cancelto{0}{f(3)} + kf(p) \implies f(p) = 0$.

This leaves only the primes $2$ and $5$.
We know from $(c)$ that $f(2) + f(5) =  0$ and since by hypothesis $f(k)\geqslant 0$ for all $k$, we conclude $f(2) = f(5) = 0$.

It follows that for all primes $p$, $f(p) = 0$.
Because we've already shown that $f(1) = 0$, it follows from $(*)$ that $f(n) = 0$ for all $n$, and it's easy to check that this indeed sastisfies all required properties. $\square$

Comment: You could combine (I) and (II) into $\gcd(p,10)=1\implies 0=f(3p^4)=f(3)+4f(p)$.

Comment: That's true! $a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ whenever $\gcd (a, n) = 1$, and $\varphi (10) = 4$.

Comment: Feel free to change your answer accordingly. Please ping me if you do, so we can delete these comments.